# when I use IDEA to create a maven project, this error occur.I don't know how does it happen

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

```
Cannot copy 'C:\Users\44030975\.m2\repository\junit\junit\4.9\junit-4.9.jar' to 'c:\sandbox\.IntelliJIdea\system\jars\junit-4.9.jar'.
     Reason: PersistentEnumerator storage corrupted c:\sandbox\.IntelliJIdea\system\jars\snapshots_info.values.
```

> IDEA version:14.1.2 ultimate.If you have ever met this problem,pls give me a hand. really thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I vaguely remember running into this at one point and if I remember correctly I was able to resolve it by cleaning the system cache. Try selecting option [File | Invalidate Caches/Restart](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/cleaning-system-cache.html). A search of the IntelliJ support [site](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us) indicates some others have had at least some luck with this approach as well.

It looks like you are using a pretty old version of IntelliJ. Are you able to upgrade to a newer version (in case the older version had some related issue that may have since been resolved)?

Comment: when I clicked Invalidate Caches/Restart , the IntelliJ got stuck. I need to ask for my manager's approve if try to update to a newer version, so it's a little troublesome.

Comment: I try this again, IntelliJ Restart succeed.but the same error still occur.